# Why I cannot download software on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, sudo

I have found out that suddenly i am unable to install ANYTHING on my ubuntu distro.
Every time I try

```
sudo apt-get install anything
```

i actually get the same error message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package adobe-flashplugin
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks)))

Comment: `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably update your repository first.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try installing with the following code.

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Also if you have GUI, you can get flash from Software Center. It's much easier if you don't find the terminal comfortable.

[Adobe Flash for Ubuntu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/adobe-flashplugin/)

Comment: That should be a lowercase `sudo`.